# Keep spawning object every second

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a function which adds the RandomBlock object to the scene and moves it down the screen.

```
function enemyPaddleMovement()
{
scene.add(RandomBlock);
RandomBlock.translateX(-8);
}
```

RandomBlock is made by this code:

```
var shapes = [LeftBlock, RightBlock, middleRightBlock, middleLeftBlock, middleBlock];
var shape = shapes[Math.floor(Math.random()*shapes.length)];`

RandomBlock = new THREE.Object3D();
RandomBlock.add(shape);
```

What I want to do is to keep spawning a new RandomBlock object every second and move it down the screen. Ive tried using setInterval but it only replaces the same RandomBlock object rather than creating a new object everytime.

any Help?

Comment: where's the code you were trying?

Comment: var block = function(){
 RandomBlock = new THREE.Object3D();
 RandomBlock.add(shape); 
 }
 
 setInterval(block, 1000);

Comment: try this `var block = function(){ var RandomBlock = new THREE.Object3D(); RandomBlock.add(shape); return RandomBlock;} setInterval(block, 1000); `

Comment: Nothing happens, thanks for replying anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem actually doesn't involve Three.js at all; it's just that you are not making any new objects, you are reusing the same one many times. Try something like this instead:

```
// this line stays outside the function
var shapes = [LeftBlock, RightBlock, middleRightBlock, middleLeftBlock, middleBlock];
```

```
function enemyPaddleMovement()
{
    var shape = shapes[Math.floor(Math.random()*shapes.length)];
    var randomBlock = new THREE.Object3D();
    randomBlock.add(shape);
    scene.add(randomBlock);
    randomBlock.translateX(-8);
}
```

Note that there are no longer any mentions of `randomBlock` outside the function. This is because it is an object for *that one call of the function* and is unique to it.

I'm assuming you wanted to pick a different shape for each new object. If you don't, then just move `var shape = ...` back outside the function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried your solution but with no luck. It got me thinking about my code structure though and I think the problem might be there.

Answer (score 0):

You need also to store this new Object. I think that you overwrite old object that is why is recreated.
Instead of RandomBlock you can have BlockContainer which will be a list.